# Did Jesus have wealth and mansion's?

Tags: life-of-jesus

Did Jesus have many mansion while on earth? I heard a teaching from T.V that he preached from his many mansion? It just does not sound right,am I wrong?

Comment: You are thinking of 'in my Father's house are many mansions' John 14:2 KJV. Which is a spiritual expression, not a material one. Jesus left only his garments when he died. Soldiers divided them and then gambled for the cloak, woven without seam.

Comment: “In my fathers house there are many mansions .”  Jesus’ father did not physically dwell on earth while his son sojourned to this planet for the purpose of ransoming mankind. It is figurative language speaking of a heavenly dwelling place.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest that you are thinking of :

> ... in my Father's house are many mansions ... John 14:2 KJV.

This is quite clearly a spiritual expression, not a material one, for Jesus clarifies the expression by saying that he is 'going to prepare a place for you', that being evidently after his death and resurrection, not an earthly situation.

As to his personal possessions and property, Jesus left only his garments when he died. Soldiers divided them and then gambled for the cloak, woven without seam, John 19:23 -24.

By so doing, these soldiers unknowingly fulfilled the prophecy spoken by David in the psalms, written about 1,000 years before the event took place :

> They part my garments among them and cast lots for my vesture. Psalm 22:18 KJV.

---

As has been supplied in comment by @L1R, Jesus says of himself :

> Foxes have holes, and birds of the air have nests; but the Son of man hath not where to lay his head. Luke 9:58, KJV.

Comment: Good answer, just like to add Luke 9:58 "Jesus replied, "Foxes have dens and birds have nests, but the Son of Man has no place to lay his head." Basically implies he was without a single (earthly) home.

Comment: @L1R Thank you. Your comment edited into my answer.

Answer (score -4):

#### Edit

*I wish to explain that a king receiving gifts in the value of today’s money exceeding $1M is not ludicrous by any means.*

I shall use the Bible

> “Then **she gave the king 120 talents of gold**, and a **very great quantity of spices and precious stones**. Never again came such an abundance of spices as these that the queen of Sheba gave to King Solomon.”
> ‭‭1 Kings‬ ‭10:10‬ ‭

I shall explain the value of the gold gift brought to Solomon.

120 talents of gold at 35kg per talent(1,234oz) and at today’s gold price per ounce $1,500 that’s $222M. Even if we say gold is inflated and should be at $200 an ounce that would still be $30M. If Jesus has received just one talent that would be $1.8M just there. That’s beside the myrrh and frankincense. Spices were incredibly valuable also. It’s highly unlikely again that they travelled, prepared and possibly even had a small personal accompanying army to protect a couple of ounces of resin.

Logically these magi spent a lot of time preparing. According to the time they first saw the star until when they finally arrived to Herod, whether the star appeared at conception of birth Herod thought it necessary to kill all children two years and under.

> “Then Herod, when he saw that he had been tricked by the wise men, became furious, and he sent and killed all the male children in Bethlehem and in all that region who were two years old or under, **according to the time that he had ascertained from the wise men**.”
> ‭‭Matthew‬ ‭2:16‬

Further these men did not travel that distance and prepare that long to bring a gift the value of $50 gift card at buybuybaby.

The text makes it evident that they were many men, enough men that Herod was not in a position to assassinate them without a fight. Enough man that it brought fear over all Jerusalem. For good reasons, this was an attempt to dethrone Herod, talking about another king

> “When Herod the king heard this, **he was troubled, and all Jerusalem with him**;”
> ‭‭Matthew‬ ‭2:3‬ ‭

This was seen as a threat. No wonder he was troubled. Herod planned to kill this king.

So clearly they didn’t bring trinkets to Jesus.

#### Original response

The idea that Jesus had financial wealth comes from the magi presenting gifts to a king. And kings are known to receive extravagant gifts from other dignitaries.

According to one source of scholars funded by Australian billionaire Mr. Peter J. Daniels the value in today’s money would be between of US$5-8Million.

However we cannot know for certain whether that be true or even if true how the money was spent. Certainly Joseph had to relocate them several times and that money would have helped especially in Egypt. But also Jesus was versed in Scriptures and it’s speculated He bought his own copies. Which take many months to produce and each cost a small fortune. And this before the age of twelve as per the temple incident.

> “After three days they found him in the temple, sitting among the teachers, listening to them and asking them questions. And all who heard him were amazed at his understanding and his answers.”
> ‭‭Luke‬ ‭2:46-47‬ ‭

If we go by, “do as you preach” and Jesus required the young rich ruler to sell all his possessions and follow Him, there is no reason to believe that Jesus would have done differently.

> “And Jesus, looking at him, loved him, and said to him, "You lack one thing: go, sell all that you have and give to the poor, and you will have treasure in heaven; and come, follow me."”
> ‭‭Mark‬ ‭10:21‬ ‭

However by the time Jesus was in ministry He had but limited amount of funds which he entrusted to Judas.

> “Some thought that, because Judas had the moneybag, Jesus was telling him, "Buy what we need for the feast," or that he should give something to the poor.”
> ‭‭John‬ ‭13:29‬ ‭

You don’t need a money bag or an accountant if you spend each day all you have and live from day to day finances. So Jesus had some money with him by this point.

Consider

> “And a scribe came up and said to him, "Teacher, I will follow you wherever you go." And Jesus said to him, "Foxes have holes, and birds of the air have nests, but **the Son of Man has nowhere to lay his head**."”
> ‭‭Matthew‬ ‭8:19-20‬

So clearly He had no permanent place of residency and did not invest in anything on earth.

He did have an expensive garment that was too valuable to shred into pieces. But we know not how he came to have it

> “so they said to one another, "Let us not tear it, but cast lots for it to see whose it shall be." This was to fulfill the Scripture which says, "They divided my garments among them, and for my clothing they cast lots." So the soldiers did these things,”
> ‭‭John‬ ‭19:24‬ ‭

But we know that while Jesus didn’t petition people for money He received money if it was given him

> “Soon afterward he went on through cities and villages, proclaiming and bringing the good news of the kingdom of God. And the twelve were with him, and also some women who had been healed of evil spirits and infirmities: Mary, called Magdalene, from whom seven demons had gone out, and Joanna, the wife of Chuza, Herod's household manager, and Susanna, and many others, **who provided for them out of their means**.”
> ‭‭Luke‬ ‭8:1-3‬ ‭

Or they gave financial support.

Comment: It's ludicrous to put any monetary value on the gold Jesus was given as we know nothing of how much he was given.

Comment: @curiousdannii take it up with Peter Daniels and the team of Bible scholars he hired.

Comment: But honestly I don’t see what’s so ludicrous, it’s not like they bought a single gold coin, one fluid ounce myrrh and one ounce of frankincense. All of which still have value today.  But one gold coin today is $1,500, 1 oz frankincense is $200 and 1 oz myrrh is $100. That’s $1,800 at a minimum. And the magi bought amounts worthy of a king, at least that’s what we are led to believe. So I don’t agree with your objection entirely but I take your point.

Comment: This is total speculation. This claim is standard rich televangelist non-sense from a billionaire with a book called How to be Happy Through Rich. Please link to external sources. Just because they didn't want to tear a seamless garment doesn't mean it was very valuable.
But yes, we can think the gifts from the magi were valuable. How valuable? If we speculate, we probably shouldn't trust a hopelessly biased source unless they provide good external evidence.

Comment: To be clear, there are several good points in this answer, such as not having anywhere to lay his head, i.e. no place of residence, like you said. That pretty much in and of itself answers the question in its entirety with an emphatic no. So, thank you for providing this answer! I would suggest removing the complete speculation parts unless there is a strong external source, and/or make the answer more clear (since the direct answer is given in Matthew 8:19-20)

Comment: @AlexStrasser I’m addressing the source of OP’s televangelist speculation. I’m not saying these are true.

Comment: Let’s just say that it was MORE valuable than a seamed garment. http://www.biblecourses.com/English/downloads/pdfs/CrossLessons/043.The_Seamless_Tunic.pdf @AlexStrasser

Comment: @Autodidact Okay. Can you you at least link to the claim from Daniels/those historians?

Comment: You're the one referencing their "research" which means you must think it's worth considering. So you have to defend it. If you don't think $5-8M is defensible then don't quote it!

Comment: It’s extremely defensible, even though that wasn’t the reason I quoted it. It’s highlighting why such a question has any veracity in the first place. One needs to have a leg to stand on when making the claim that Jesus had a lot of wealth. What are they basing it on? Clearly his parents were poor given their circumcision animal. But they came into some money when the magi came by. There is no other example where Jesus could have attained wealth and it was important to establish at a minimum this is a possibility. So it’s up to us to discredit the magi hypothesis because it’s a great hypothesis